# Why does a lack of inversion symmetry in 2D pattern formation lead to hexagons?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system, biology

In reaction diffusion based pattern formation (or other types of pattern formation too, really), it seems that the absence of an inversion symmetry (i.e., if the field $u(x,t)$ is a stable solution/steady state, then $-u(x,t)$ is not) leads to hexagonal pattern formation (rather than stripes or squares). This can be seen, for example, in the references [1](https://pubs.aip.org/aip/jcp/article-abstract/72/3/1900/971506/Pattern-selection-at-the-bifurcation-point), [2](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/pattern-formation-and-dynamics-in-nonequilibrium-systems/3FD268DBA3E28117E44D3BA03F6E4D33), [3](https://journals.aps.org/rmp/pdf/10.1103/RevModPhys.65.851),
[4](https://www.cell.com/neuron/pdf/S0896-6273(22)00907-2.pdf),[5](https://journals.aps.org/pra/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevA.99.053851) and several other sources.

However, I am unable to come up with a simple mathematical explanation, or intuitive reason for this; and the explanations in the above references seem to be quite detailed or scenario specific. Why does a lack of inversion symmetry generally lead to hexagons in pattern formation?